# Calculating bytes from sextets in C/C++ for steganography

Tags: c++, c, steganography

This should be a simple question. I'm well advanced in developing steganographic code in C, which required manipulating the least significant bit in each R, G, and B channel of a 24 bit (3 byte) pixel of an image. A pair of pixels has 6 bits (which I call a sextet for want of a better word) that can be used, and I have developed code that converts a buffer in bytes to a buffer in sextets, where each byte in the latter buffer only uses the 6 lower order bits, with the upper 2 bits being discarded when changing pixels. This all works correctly, and I can encode text in any language in an image.

In doing this the application calculates the number of sextets that can be embedded in an image. However, it is useful to know how many bytes can be processed, as both the input is originally in bytes, and the output is recovered in bytes. As 4 sextets correspond to 3 bytes, I'm using the statement:

```
    maxNumBytes = (3 * maxNumSexts - 2 * (maxNumSexts % 4)) / 4;
```

which converts and rounds down to a multiple of 3, where maxNumSexts and maxNumBytes are respectively the maximum number of sextets and bytes that can be hidden in an RGB image, and these two variable have the type int32_t. This formula works but is rather cumbersome, and I was wondering if someone could find something simpler that works correctly.

Incidentally, although the code is in C, this applies exactly in C++, hence that has been included as a tag, and some C++ code may be added later.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why isn't this just `(3 * maxNumSexts) / 4`?

Comment: Bytes are octets probably. They are not strictly synonymous, but on most machines they are the same. Each pixel encodes a triplet, i.e. three bit. Calculating in sextets (what for?) doesn't seem to make much sense as intermediate. BTW: Do you know base64?

Comment: Yes, I know about base64, and in fact I modified such code I found online to encode binary data in bytes into sextets that will be embedded in images, such as executable code that can be hidden. The challenge is that a sextet can only contain 64 values, and a terminating sextet, such as zero cannot be used. Instead the first few sextets encode the length of the data.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you're even asking. "something simpler" is not an objective goal. In any case, plug `maxNumSextets = 2` into your formula above and you get zero, which is clearly wrong. At least in my understanding of what it's supposed to be. Little of this has anything to do with C or C++, btw, let alone steganography.

Comment: (3 * maxNumSexts) / 4 is the obvious choice, but does not work. If maxNumSexts takes, say, the values 24, 25. 25, 27, 28, the respective outputs are 18, 18, 19, 20, 21. The first two and last outputs are correct but the other two are wrong. The formula I suggested return 18 for the first four inputs, then 21 for the last, which is correct. In general, If maxNumSexts is a multiple of 4, 1 greater, 2 greater or 3 greater, it will return a multiple of 3. If it is 4 greater, it will return the next largest multiple of 3.

Comment: Actually maxNumSextets = 2 returning zero is what I want as zero is trivially a multiple of 3 and anything else. In any case it makes no sense to use small numbers. In the working code a realistic minimum number is required.

Comment: For example (3 * 27) / 4 = 20.25, which when truncated to an integer is 20, however, I want all values between 24 and 27 to evaluate to 18, and likewise values between 28 and 31 to evaluate to 21, etc. In calculating the number of sextets in an image, based on the width, height, and any padding bytes, I just want to get an idea of the number of bytes that this is equivalent to. A typical UFT-8 encoding of, say, Manderin, contains 16 bits of data. This is converted to 3 sextets of 18 bits, with the additional 2 bits being used as flags indicating a space, line feed etc.

Comment: In fact the French word for a byte is indeed an octet. I've heard that 4 bits make a nibble, or is it a nybble?

Answer (score 0):

> I want all values between 24 and 27 to evaluate to 18, and likewise values between 28 and 31 to evaluate to 21, etc.

Since you want only multiples of 3, the last operation should be the multiplication by 3. And the "steps" on the input value is by 4 increments.  So you can use this formula in integer arithmetic:

`maxNumBytes = 3 * (maxNumSexts / 4);`

---

*Note 1: However, the actual number of bytes encoded by 27 sextets is 20, because 27 sextets contain 81 bits.*

*Note 2: Yes, a half byte is called a "[nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)", from the verb. The form "nybble" is known, but rarely used.*

Comment: Note that `/` rounds down, so you might actually want `3 * ((maxNumSexts + 3)/4)` in order to round up instead. But it is not clear what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for pointing that out. I know, and the OP wants it like that. Please see my citation.

Comment: Many thanks, I've just tested (A) (3 * num - 2 * (num % 4)) / 4, (B) 3 * (num / 4) and (C) 3 * ((num + 3) / 4). (A) and (B) are always the same, and (C) is 3 larger except when num is a multiple of 4, in which case it is the same. This even works for values between 0 and 4. As I want to round down, and (B) is simpler than (A), (B) will be used. This reminds me of when I was at school in England in the 1960s. I was asked what is 5 10ths of a Shilling (there were 12 Pennies to a Shilling), and I thought about it for a while missing the obvious that it is 6 Pennies.

Comment: (B) and (C) as mentioned above can be generalized for rounding down as m * (num / n),  and for rounding up as m * ((num + m) / n), where num is the input integer, n > m, n is not a multiple of m, and the ratio m:n is reduced to the lowest integer values, i.e. 6:8 is the same as 3:4, which is the case here.

Comment: Glad to help. The usual way to say "thank you" is to mark the answer as accepted. ;-) This also helps future visitors to recognize the issue as solved.